# Pass function pointer as part of a hash, perl

Tags: perl, class, pointers

The script runs such that THE USER defines some function:

```
sub userFunction
{
 my ($msg, $id) = @ARG;
 # do things
}
```

This function, $func is passed with a specific message name, $msg, into my class to be stored as a $msg/$userFunc pair in {_Handles}:

```
sub new
{
  my ($class, ...) = @_;
  my $self = {};
  $self->{_Handles} = {};
  .
  . 
  .
}
```

Then I add a message handler:

```
$Class->AddMsgHandler($msgName1, \&userFunction);
sub AddMsgHandler
{ 
  my ($self, $msg, $func) = @ARG;
  my $funcPtr = $func->();
  $self->{_Handles}{'msg'} = $msg;
  $self->{_Handles}{$msg}{'funcPtr'} = $funcPtr;
}
```

The intention is to transfer my message wirelessly across a device; another device will receive this message. Assuming the device receives the message in another function, I'm trying to call the user defined function on specific $id as follows:

```
sub Receive
{
 .
 .
 .
 my $funcPtr = $self->{_Handles}{$msg}{'funcPtr'};
 $funcPtr->($msg, $self->{_devices}{$id});
}
```

somehow there's no response. Perhaps I have misused the function pointer?

Comment: I don't understand. You're already calling the user defined function here: `my $funcPtr = $func->();`

Comment: What do you mean, "another device"? Are you talking about two perl programs (client/server)? Or what code is running where?

Comment: This is information transmitted wirelessly, there's a framework that will send these messages to separate devices for reception

Comment: So how can a device "receive the message in another function" if the program isn't running on that device?

Comment: fyi, "code reference" or "cref" for short is the more Perlish way to describe a function pointer.

Comment: 2c: I've never seen "cref", only "coderef" (code reference") or "subref" (subroutine reference).

Comment: 2c: I use "coderef" in text, and often leading `rc` in code, like `$rc_name` or `$rcname`. It goes with `rh`  for hashref and `ra` (or just `r`) for arrayref (when these are needed).

Comment: I don't know how I forgot "coderef" ;)

Comment: I've never seen `cref` either. Maybe you mean `CV` (the internal name for the type)? If you're suggesting variable names, I've seen `$cb` (callback) and `$cv`. `$code`, `$code_ref`, `$code_ptr`, `$func`, `$func_ref` and `$func_ptr` are perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this: `my $funcPtr = $func->();`, you're executing the subroutine and assigning the function's return value to `$funcPtr`, not the function's code reference itself, which I think is what you're after. You need to remove the `->()` from that assignment. Here's a brief example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %store;

sub user_func {
    return 5;
}
sub set {
    my $func = shift;
    $store{func} = $func;
}

set(\&user_func);

print $store{func}->();
```

Here's an example that shows the difference:

```
sub func {
    return 5;
}

my $cref = \&func;

my $called = $cref->();
my $not_called = $cref;

print "$called\n";
print "$not_called\n";
```

Output:

```
5
CODE(0x801c82ed0)
```

Comment: This was helpful, as you earlier mentioned, it makes sense that it would be the return value and not the reference that gets assigned

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the best possible help is to guide you to debug your own code. You can use the **-d** flag to turn on Perl debugger so you can stop the execution of code to ensure:

1. You are really storing a sub reference
2. You are really restoring it and calling it

Saying that, I would turn on my quick solution:

instead of

```
$funcPtr->($msg, $self->{_devices}{$id});
```

**try**

```
&$funcPtr($msg, $self->{_devices}{$id});
```

Comment: `&$f()` does exactly the same thing as `$f->()`. The `&` syntax is just a bit more dangerous because it does something different if you forget the `()`.